# Linear Algebra Tensor Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, tensors

I want to ask for a general linear algebra formula that I found in the book [Nonnegative Matrix and Tensor Factorizations](https://books.google.de/books/about/Nonnegative_Matrix_and_Tensor_Factorizat.html?id=KaxssMiWgswC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) in page 370, is that we can replace $\textbf{U}^{\otimes ^{-n}} \textbf{G}_{(n)}^T$ by $\overline{\textbf{X}}^T_{(n)} \textbf{U}^{(n)^{\dagger^T}}$

Specifying the rule with $N = 3$ and $n = 1$,

$(\textbf{U}^{(2)} \otimes \textbf{U}^{(3)})  \textbf{G}_{(1)}^T = \overline{\textbf{X}}^T_{(1)}  \textbf{U}^{(1)^{\dagger^T}}$

I used this formula in an algorithm that wasn't converging except once every 10 times and then after doing this replacement it converged every single time.

> **Just for clarification this is for tucker decomposition,**
>
> $\cal{X} = \mathcal{G} \times_1 \textbf{U}^{(1)} \times_2 \textbf{U}^{(2)} \times_3 \textbf{U}^{(3)}$ for $N=3$ as $N$ is the order of the tensor $\mathcal{X}$, while $\mathcal{G}$ is the core tensor, $U^{(n)}$ are tensor factors.
>
> $\textbf{U}^{(n)^T}$ is the transpose of nth factor matrix
>
> $\times_n$ is the n-product
>
> $\otimes$ is the kronecker product
>
> $\dagger$ is the pseudo inverse
>
> $\overline{\textbf{X}}_{(n)}$ over bar shows that this is the result of estimation of the unfolding n of the tensor $\mathcal{X}$
>
> $\textbf{U}^{\otimes -n} = \textbf{U}^{(N)} \otimes ... \otimes \textbf{U}^{(n+1)} \otimes \textbf{U}^{(n-1)} \otimes ... \times \textbf{U}^{(1)}$
>
> $\textbf{G}_{(n)}$ is the nth unfolding of the core tensor

**Here is my question,**

First I thought that both formulas would give the same result with difference in calculations cost.  I need help how to confirm that both calculations are different or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found my mistake while writing the question,

I replaced the numbers in the kronecker product
$\textbf{U}^{(2)} \otimes \textbf{U}^{(3)} \neq \textbf{U}^{(3)} \otimes  \textbf{U}^{(2)}$

and confirmed that the formulas are the same as follows,

The unfolding formula for Tucker $\textbf{X}_{(1)} = \textbf{U}^{(1)} \textbf{G}_{(1)} (\textbf{U}^{(3)} \otimes \textbf{U}^{(2)})^T$

then by using the formula in the book  $\textbf{U}^{\otimes ^{-n}} \textbf{G}_{(n)}^T$ by $\overline{\textbf{X}}^T_{(n)} \textbf{U}^{(n)^{\dagger^T}}$

$\textbf{X}_{(1)} = \textbf{U}^{(1)} \textbf{U}^{(1)^{\dagger}} \overline{\textbf{X}}_{(1)}$ and because $\textbf{U}^{(n)}$ is orthogonal so it will come true.